# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и»? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, и

Уважаемые знатоки пунктуации, подскажите, нужна ли запятая в данном примере?

*Сначала я вынашивал план(,) **и** как именно его нужно осуществить.*

Answer (score 1):

*Сначала я вынашивал план(,) и как именно его нужно осуществить.*
Ваше предложение мне представляется некорректным. И здесь, думаю, дело не в запятой, а, собственно, в смысле всего предложения.

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[выносить](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) (вынашивать) — обдумать до полной ясности, зрелости. *Выносить идею.*

В толковом словаре Ефремовой:
[вынашивать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/151496/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — обдумывать что-либо до полной ясности, завершённости.

Если вы *вынашиваете план* (отмщения, нападения, захвата, переворота), то считается, что в нем продумываются и пути (методы) его реализации — по определению (на то он и план).

Мне кажется, что предложение может быть приблизительно таким:
Сначала [какое-то время] я вынашивал план, а потом [теперь] приступил к его осуществлению.

Comment: Давайте представим, что смысловое наполнение в данном случае не релевантно. Пускай будет предложение "Сначала я обдумывал план(,) и как именно его нужно осуществить" и менять его нельзя. Куда поставить запятую? Я так понимаю, вторая часть - односоставное безличное предложение и запятая нужна. Но нет уверенности.